# Реализация android чата

Tags: android, сервер, chat, client

Здравствуйте. Я новичок. Я ищу актуальный способ реализации чата в Android приложениях.
Я конечно понимаю, что сейчас может начаться "IT драка"... Но все же...
Пример:
Есть сервер, который по запросу http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/getMessages возвращает JsonArray объект со списком сообщений.

```
[
    {
    "id": 13,
    "user_fio": "Андрей Антонов",
    "user_photo": "http://.../ava.jpg",
    "text": "Сообщение",
    "image": "http://.../image.jpg",
    "when": "2017-06-12 02:22:47",
    "is_read": false,
    "user": 22
    },
    {
    "id": 14,
    "user_fio": "Максим Андреев",
    "user_photo": "http://.../ava.jpg",
    "text": "Сообщение 2",
    "image": http://.../image2.jpg,
    "when": "2017-06-17 06:11:01",
    "is_read": true,
    "user": 53
    }
]
```

На сколько я понял это один из примеров RestFul серверов(не бейте, если я не прав)

Потом я понял, что получать сообщения в реальном времени не так уж просто...
Нужно как-то мониторить эти события... И наткнулся на целый лес:
Ajax, XMPP, socet'ы и некоторые другие аббревиатуры... Прежде чем изучать одну из них я пытался выяснить актуальность хотя-бы одной из них(может что-то устарело).
И в итоге я вообще заблудился...
Все что я хочу узнать - это какие библиотеки, паттерны... используют сейчас для реализации чатов... Можно ли как-то реализовывать чаты через сокеты с серверами, которые только по запросу предоставляют список сообщений(как выше)....
И если в приложении присутствуют сообщения не только тет-а-тет, но и групповые, меняет ли это технологию обмена сообщениями в реальном времени...
На данный момент получилось реализовать работу с сервером с помощью rxJava и retrofit... На этом я пока остановился.
Если можно, то хотя бы укажите, что изучать...
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Николай, для новичка достаточно простая реализация чата - это с помощью Firebase. Много туториалов, проблем не возникнет. Если же ваш чат должен взаимодействовать со своим сервером, то вкратце вот как это происходить должно:
 1. Приложение регистрируется в GCM
 2. После успешной регистрации он вам выдает токен
 3. Вы отправляете этот токен на сервер
 4. Сервер говорит GCM отправить сообщение юзеру с неким токеном
 5. GCM отправляет этому юзеру push-уведомление
 6. Юзер получает push
Эти пуши и есть ваши реалтайм сообщения по сути. Думаю тут достаточно чтобы вы смогли нагуглить все что не понятно и тогда сложится картина того как это реализовать.

Comment: Я так понимаю, сервер выступает в роли посредника между мной и GCM(приложение отправляет post запрос на сервер, сервер сообщает GCM, а GCM отправляет другому юзеру пуш). А что делать если сервер уже готов, поправить код не возможности. И все что он может, это возвращать JsonArray структуру чата,
а POST запросом просто добавлять в базу отправленные сообщения?
Я так понимаю, здесь выход один... Это просто каждые n секунд мониторить новые сообщения?

Comment: Скорее GCM выступает в роли посредника между сервером и клиентом. В вашем случае я считаю оптимальным создать сервис, который будет каждые n секунд стучатся к серверу. Для того чтобы это настроить лучше использовать JobScheduler или его аналоги, в зависимости от минимального api в вашем приложении. Это позволит ловить сообщения даже когда само приложение было убито, и, например выводить пуш.

Comment: Спасибо! Так и сделаю)